# Not sure where to put the where clause In codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been looking over the active records guide from codeigniters site and I am trying to figure where to put the where clause, in the model or controller? I think it goes in the model, but not sure how to implement it. $where = "EmpName='Donny"; $this->db->where($where);

Controller called Home.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Home extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index() 
    {

        $this->load->model('HomeModel');
        $data['records'] = $this->HomeModel->getData();
        $this->load->view('HomeView',$data);
    }
}
```

HomeModel.php

```
<?php 

class HomeModel extends CI_Model{

public function getData(){

    $query = $this->db->get('requests');
    return $query->result();
}

}
```

HomeView.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Our DB Results:</h1>
    <?php 

foreach($records as $r){

echo $r->EmpName."   ".$r->Department."<br>";

};?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I left a comment and someone left an answere and it has been deleted? thats wierd

Comment: Yes..put your where clause in model file only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('requests', array(  'EmpName' => 'Donny'  ));
return $query->result();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('requests', array('id' => $id));
```

you can use

```
$this->db->where('empname', 'Donny');
```

Comment: there is no ID in the db it is called RequestNumber but when I add that says variable not defined

Comment: @Donny..yes agree..i have given only example for solution..hope change it with correct table field it will work..Thanks